# Counting consecutive numbers

Tags: java, loops, scope

I am currently stuck on how to count consecutive numbers inputted by the user. I am trying to do `a=lastvariable` but `lastvariable` stays 0. I know about variable scope, but how do I change `a=lastvariable`?

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Give a positive #: ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        int consecutive= 0;
        int lastvariable=0;


        while(input>0){
            System.out.print("Give a positive #: ");
            int a = scan.nextInt();
            if(a==lastvariable)
                 consecutive++;
            if (a<0)
                input = 0;
            a = lastvariable;
        }
        System.out.println("Consecutive #'s: " + consecutive);
    }
```

Comment: **Thank you for any help!**

Comment: `a = lastvariable` means "Put the value of `lastvariable` into `a`".

Comment: The first time you get input (while not in the `while` loop), you're not assigning that value to `lastvariable`, not sure if that's intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop this way. You did a minor error of not setting lastvariable.

`while(input>0){
            System.out.print("Give a positive #: ");
            int a = scan.nextInt();
            if(a==lastvariable)
                 consecutive++;
            if (a<0)
                input = 0;
             lastvariable = a; //small correction here
        }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (a<0) input = 0;
lastvariable = a;
```

Comment: Please add some description on how it would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You never set lastvariable to an other value.

```
    a = lastvariable;
```

means that you set a to the value which is stored in lastvariable, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = lastvariable;
```

is assigning `a` to `lastvariable`'s value, which, in your current code, will always be `0`. You must do this instead:

```
lastvariable = a;
```